# How to gracefully terminate a TestNG test?

Tags: java, testng

Some of my TestNG tests involve persistent data usage. When the test is finished some actions should be performed to restore the state of data (e.g. cleaning up). I solve this using `@AfterClass` or `@AfterMethod`.

The problem is that sometimes during the development my test hangs up and I need to terminate it manually. When terminating JVM process running test I have to perform all post-test actions by myself.

Is there any way I can terminate the test so that my `@After*` methods are invoked?

Comment: Don't you mean `@AfterClass` or `@AfterMethod` for your cleanup? (@BeforeXXX are for *setup*, not *clean up*)

Comment: @Bohemian indeed, I meant `@After` :) thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to create a *shutdown hook* via [`Runtime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)'s [`addShutdownHook`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29)  method, like this:

```
static volatile boolean cleanedUp = false;
static final Object lock = new Object();

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            MyTestClass.tearDown();
        }
    }
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDown() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (cleanedUp) return;
        // do clean up
        cleanedUp = true; 
    }         
}
```

Using the synchronization ensures the clean up is only executed once.

Comment: TestNG allows using non-static @AfterClass (and I use this one), so I'll have to pass instance of my test class to the Runnable. Also it seems like in case of a successful execution without hanging up, my `@After*` method will be invoked twice - first by TestNG framework, then by hook. Am I right? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: a) Make your `@AfterClass` static... you're allowed to. b) set a `static volatile boolean` flag in your method and check that it hasn't *already* been set before proceeding - that way it'll only execute clean up *once*

Comment: I think you're both missing the point, he is in a situation where one of his tests is locking up TestNG and he wants the After* methods to be run anyway. If you're using a shutdown hook, by that time, the JVM is shutting down so the cleanup in After* will never be performed. I'll answer in a separate comment.

Comment: @CedricBeust You're wrong there - this answer is correct and will work as per OP's requirements: When the JVM is stopped manually, like using Ctrl-c, the shutdown hooks are guaranteed to be fired. Using this code forces the "after" methods to be called. The added synronization guarantees the clean up code is not run more than once.

Comment: Well, first of all, let's let the OP say if I'm wrong (he said I'm not, by the way, read above). And you are wrong about the shutdown hook. If the VM is shutting down, it will forcefully kill all the threads before invoking the shutdown hooks, which means that TestNG's after methods will never be invoked.

Comment: @CedricBeust OMG... I *know* TestNg's methods will not get invoked if the JVM is killed. That's where the shutdown hook comes in - it runs the method instead! Please read my code. Notice the `MyTestClass.tearDown();`? The shutdown hook is calling the `@AfterClass` method *directly* (and the boolean flag logic ensures the clean up only runs once). I suspect you don't understand how shutdown hooks work - read [this java] doc(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) for a basic overview.

Comment: I have just coded sample test with shutdown hook and here are the results. I'm using Eclipse and Ubuntu Linux, and when pressing "stop" button in Eclipse the hook doesn't work, because the process is killed (with SIGKILL I guess). But then I tried finding the process through terminal and executing `kill <PID>` - this sends SIGTERM to process and the hook works. I haven't tried the solution for Windows but so far it is a working solution that satisfies my requirements.

Comment: Because of the need to deal with details of process termination, the approach with hook can't be really reliable and can't be part of standard development cycle. But anyway the hanging of functional test is not a usual situation. So I think you guys should not argue here - your answers are applicable for different situations (that's why I up-voted both): for small unit tests I would use timeout and for specific cases of long functional tests with unknown or varying duration I would add shutdown hook, so I can manually stop test without waiting. The later is my case so I accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want TestNG to continue even if you have tests that lock up, you could put a time out on these tests so TestNG kills them after a certain period of time. After this, you After* methods should be called as usual:

```
@Test(timeOut = 10000) // 10 seconds
public void f() {...}
```

Comment: This approach is really good, but can be applied only to fast tests or tests with some fixed and known duration. My test is a kind of functional test which may last several minutes (I run it not as part of standard build, so running other tests after the lock up occurred is not an issue for me). The duration may vary so I don't want waiting too much when it's already obvious the hanging occured, neither I want to fail test only because it didn't managed to finish in time. This two problems are opposite when choosing timeout value.

Comment: But there is *some* time out value since you need to decide when your test is truly dead and should be aborted, right? Just use that value in the time out.

Comment: In some cases - yes and in some cases - no. For my functional test I use standard output to check its execution. Of course I can add timeout with some value large enough to guarantee that the test will finish in case no hang up occurs (so that if I plan the full build with this test included, it will eventually be completed), but i need more precise control for situations when I need to work with test quickly. I realize that using timeout is a reliable way to solve the problem of hang up but it has its drawback - waiting. See my comments to Bohemian's answer.